# Theorem 1 in Fulton's algebraic curves section 3.2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am reading section 3.2 in Fulton's Algebraic Curves.

Theorem 1. Let $F$ be an irreducible plane curve, $P\in F$. $P$ is a simple point of F if and only if $O_p(F)$ is a discrete valuation ring.

Theorem 2. Let $P$ be a point on an irreducible curve F. Then for all sufficiently large n,
$m=dim_k(m_p(F)^n/m_p(F)^{n+1})$ where $m$ is multiplicity of F at p and $m_p(F)$ is a unique maximal ideal of $O_p(F)$.

It proves $\gets$ direction of Theorem 1 by using Theorem 2 and problem 2.50 in this book.
But it needs the condition, which $k\to O_p(F)\to O_p(F)/m_p(F) $ is isomorphism to apply problem 2.50.
I was trying to prove $O_p(F)/m_p(F)$ is ring finite over $k$(algebraically closed field) to show that homomorphism is an isomorphism, but I failed. I need help or some hints. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from Nullstellensatz: the quotient $O_P(F)/m_P(F)$ is a field which is a finite type $k$-algebra hence is a finite extension. It is then algebraic over $k$ so, from the closure of $k$, equal to $k$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know the coordinate ring of F is finitely generated k algebra, but I don't know how to deal with the denominator part of its local ring at P. Could you give me more details?

Comment: I guess that $O_P(F)/m_P(F)$ is the localization of $O(F)/m_P(F)$. The last is $k$, so for the first. Isn't?

Comment: What is $O(F)$ ?

Comment: It is the function ring. If $F$ is affine, of equation $f(x,y)=0$ then $O(F)=k[x,y]/(f(x,y))$.

Comment: I see. But I still need clarification about what $O(F)/m_p(F)$ is since $m_p(F)$  isn't contained in $O(F)$ but in $O_p(F)$.

Comment: $m_P(F)$ is in $O(F)$: it is the maximal ideal of polynomial function in $O(F)$ which equals 0 in $P$. For example in the parabola $F=y-x^2$ we have $O(F)=k[x,y]/(y-x^2)$ and with $P=(1,1)$ we have $m_P(F)$ is the image of $(x-1,y-1)$ in the quotient.

Comment: In Fulton's note, $m_p(F)$ is a set of 'rational functions' defined at p whose value is zero at p. So, $m_p(F)$ is in the quotient field of $O(F)$.

Comment: Ok, so let us write $\mathfrak{m}_P(F)$ for the maximal ideal in $O(F)$. What I said is that $O_P(F)/m_P(F)$ is equal to $O(F)/\mathfrak{m}_P(F)$.